# save serial input 1:1 in python

Tags: python, serialization, save, pyserial

I'm quite new to python so I got several question. 
I've got an arduino with an sd card interface which stores a binary file with some data. Let's call it SAFEFILE.BIN. 
The main thing I want to do is, sending the data over the serial port and create a 1:1 copy on my pc with a python program for further operations.

Here is the part which I'm using to write the serial output of the Arduino to a file (serial port is open and is sending data):

```
f = open('SAFEFILE.BIN, 'w+')
while aux != b'':
      aux = ser.readline()
      f.write(aux)
else:
      print('Copy of SAFEFILE.BIN succesfully created')
      f.close()
```

The Arduino code is just:

```
File dataFile = SD.open(datafile);
if (dataFile) {
  while (dataFile.available()) {
    Serial.write(dataFile.read());}
```

Everything is working so far. The file is getting filled with my data. But after a closer look I mentioned some problems. I compared the two files (the original on the arduino and the copy of it) by reading the hex information with hex Editor

[Original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhx55.png)

[Saved file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So4LE.jpg)

As you can see the write() or the reading process seems to interprete the "0A" as a linefeed and adds a carriagereturn "0D" in front of it. In my case the 0A just means 10. 
Is there a way to stop python adding some bytes i dont need? All i want to do is to save the serial input byte per byte without any interpretation or editing.

I tried to decode and encode the read-operation with various formats, no luck so far.

For the next steps i need this safefile to be absolutely correct, giving me two options:

1. Trying to get the saveprocess right
2. search in the savefile for the bytecombination of "0D 0A" and replace it with 0A

I would definitely prefer option 1! Is there anybody who can help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the arduino, you are sending the information with `Serial.write()`, which simply sends the packets, with no line ending.  You are then reading with pythons `serial.readline()`  which takes an input stream and looks for a line ending and splits it there.  If you don't want to have any line endings and just raw data, use python's `serial.read(bytes)`  which when you don't give a bytes number, it will read continuously in non-blocking mode.  Docs on pythons serial here:  https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html#readline
So your code could look like:

```
f = open('SAFEFILE.BIN, 'wb')
while aux != b'':
    aux = ser.read()
      f.write(bytearray(aux))
else:
    print('Copy of SAFEFILE.BIN succesfully created')
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sadly the problem still exists even if I use read() instead of readline(). So it seems to be the write() process which is causing this problem.

Comment: Ok try `f.write(bytearray(aux))` that should pass a byte object to write.

Comment: Ok, how have you opened the file that you are writing to?  If it is in text-mode it will add an extra carriage return.  Can you make sure your `f.open()` looks something like `f.open('outputfile.bin', 'wb')` with the `wb` standing for write binary.

Comment: This did the trick for me! Thank you a lot! I used "w+" the whole time. Again, thank you for the help!